# Capture the browser screen as JPG/PNG/etc with Flash?

Tags: flash, screen, capture, getpixel

Is there a way to create a screenshot of the browser in Flash? I know that in Java this is possible, and it will popup a dialog asking for trusting the signed Applet, but is there a way to do this in Flash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash has not really a security model such as Java or Silverlight so things that are downright intrusive are out of question. Except for the the clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using [html2canvas.hertzen.com](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) It uses JavaScript, but it works. (Unless you need it all right in the flash, then never mind.)